# Simultaneous video recording on Raspberry Pi, using Pi camera and USB camera

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing, pi, picamera

I'm working on a RPi wildlife monitor and want to be able to record video using the Raspberry Pi camera module at the same time as an USB mini FLIR thermal camera.

Currently I'm using python's picamera module to continously record 20s of video and if motion is detected by the PIR sensor the 10 seconds either side of the motion are saved to a USB. I'd like to add a thermal recording in there, too. I've tried using multiprocessing and openCV to do it, and it will save a video and a thermal file, however the thermal recording does not open and trying to play it on the RPi crashes VLC and often also the Pi.

Does anyone have any suggestions on whether this is even achievable? I'm still somewhat of a beginner at coding.

Here is the code at the moment, I know it's probably not the best way it could be done, but it works for audio and video.

```
MotionDetected = False

#set pin that pir sensor is connected to 
pir = MotionSensor(4)

#allow pir to settle
sleep(5)
print('Ready!')

#set directory for videos and audio
audiopath= "/home/pi/testing/"
videopath= "/home/pi/testing/"

#record temp in log file
temp = gz.CPUTemperature().temperature

#start recording a circular stream that keeps 20 seconds of video
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution=(1280, 720)
stream = picamera.PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds=20)
camera.start_recording(stream, format='h264')


#parameters for audio recording
samplerate = 250000 #in Hz
duration = 10 #in seconds


# function for recording video
def save_video():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='NatBatVideo.log', format='%(filename)s [%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
                        level=logging.INFO)
    videofilename = "Video-" + datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M.%S") +".h264"
    camera.wait_recording(10)
    stream.copy_to(videopath + videofilename, seconds=20) #set number of seconds that need to be copied to video
    start_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=20)
    start = start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
    end_time = datetime.now()
    end = end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
    logging.info("%s ~ %s (%f) %s" %(start, end,(end_time-start_time).total_seconds(), temp))
    #print("Video Recording finished!")
    sleep(2)


# audio settings
# frequency threshold = 10 kHz
# volume threshold = 1%
# sample rate = 250,000 Hz
# channel = 1
# length of audio recording = 5 seconds

# function for recording audio
def record_audio():
    #Use the date and time to name the audio file
    audioname = audiopath +"Audio-" + Time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M.%S") +".wav"
    #record a 10 second audio file
    soundcommand =  ['rec', '-c' ,'1', '-r', '250000', audioname, 'sinc', '10k', 'silence' ,'1', '0.001', '1%', 'trim', '0', '10']
    call(soundcommand)
    
def FindTheTime():
    #get the time so video can be named
    Time = datetime.now()
    return Time

def record_thermal():
    # Read from the thermal camera. The index sometimes changes from 0to 1 when the pi restarts.
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1) 

    # Check if camera has opened successfully
    if (cap.isOpened() == False): 
      print("The camera did not open.")

    # Set resolutions of frame and convert from float to integer
    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

    #Create VideoWriter object and store the output in a .avi file, named using the date and time
    #Set file paths and duration

    videopath='/home/pi/testing/'
    #videopath='/media/usb/'
    duration = 10 #in seconds. This is not exact.
    end_time= datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=duration)

    video_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    video_output= cv2.VideoWriter(videopath + 'Thermal-' + datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M.%S") + '.avi',
                          video_cod,
                          10,
                          (frame_width,frame_height))


    # records for set duration (roughly)
    while datetime.now() < end_time:
          ret, frame = cap.read()

          if ret == True:
            # Write the frame into the file
            video_output.write(frame)

            # Display the frame 
            #cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

            # Press x on keyboard to end recording
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
             break
            
         #Break the loop
          else:
            break  

    # release video capture and video write objects
    cap.release()
    video_output.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 


# while loop that uses PIR motion detection
try:
    while True:
        logging.basicConfig(filename='NatBatVideo.log', format='%(filename)s [%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
                        level=logging.INFO)

        pir.wait_for_motion()
        
        print("Motion detected!")
        Time = FindTheTime()
        Process(target= save_video).start()
        Process(target= record_audio).start() 
        Process(target= record_thermal).start() 
        # sleep for 1 second longer than recording, otherwise it won't work
        sleep(11)
        print("Video recorded.")
        print("Audio recorded.")
        print("Thermal video recorded")
finally:
    camera.stop_recording()
```

Thanks!

I've tried commenting out the camera and just running the thermal recording but it still creates video files that won't open. Reduced thermal recording to 2 seconds, but still has the same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need multiple processes for this, they often make code more complicated than it needs to be.  I'd also not suggest opening a device in one process and then working with it in another (i.e. you're opening in the video in parent process and then consuming it in another process in the `save_video` function)

Comment: Can you grab the frames from IR sensor?

Comment: Are the images  from the thermal camera really in colour (3 channel)? Because you (implicitly, by leaving the last parameter at its default value) told `cv2.VideoWriter` that you will be feeding it colour frames. Trying to write grayscale (1 channel) images in such situation won't work.